# How to insert array value in cake php

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have define array value in multiple select value drop down but when we submit the form it is showing multiple array value error.

Please advice.

Comment: you want to save multiple values on a single field ?

Comment: yes tahiri i want to save multiple array values in one field

Answer (score 0):

Use the `serialize()` function to serialize all the inputs in one value

```
$this->request->data['Model']['multiple'] = serialize($this->request->data('Model.multiple'));
```

and if you want to retrieve data use `unserialize()` to get your array as it saved .

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose I do array_implode in the beforeValidate function, and array_explode in the afterFind function.